# Limit of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f \left(\lim_{n \to ∞} a_n\right).$$ 
where $a_n \to x_0$ as $n \to \infty$, and $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

My thought: If we prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = \infty$ and somehow prove the same for the other one.

Comment: Write down the definition of continuity of a function at a point in a rigorous way.

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? Your thought clearly doesn't work -- take $f(x) = x$ which is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your thought is wrong. For example, if $a_n = \frac1n$ and $f(x) = \sin x$, then you *cannot* prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = \infty$, because that is simply not true.

That said, here is a **Hint**:

- Write down the definition of when the limit of $a_n$ is equal to $L$.
- Write down the definition of when $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Compare the two definitions. They look very similar.

Now,

1. Write down what you have to prove.
2. Write down what you know.

Look at what you wrote and start thinking very hard.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that if a function is continuous, you can switch the limit and the f operators.

It's clear that the RHS is $f(x_0)$. All that remains is to show that the limit of the sequence of functions $f(a_1), f(a_2), \dots$ is $f(x_0)$. Use the definition of the limit:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|f(x_0) - f(a_n)| < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$

Definition of continuity of $f(x)$ at $x_0$:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - x_0| < \delta$

Guess:

Try something like $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x) - f(a_n) + f(a_n) - f(x_0)|$

$\le |f(x) - f(a_n)| + |f(a_n) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$